# Debian 10.4 / Exim 4.92 add incremental delay to the unsuccessful login attempt answer

Tags: debian, spam, exim

Browsed over all the internet, but cannot find an answer. Is there any acl or something that I could apply to unsuccessful login attempt to add delay to it? As probably anyone running mx, I have a lot of bots logins trying to guess users passwords. To make dictionary attacks at least a bit more difficult, I'd like to add some (incremental is better) delay after each unsuccessful login attempt's answer.
But cannot find how to do that with standard debian exim installation. Please share one with a brief explanation.

Comment: Never mind that, just use fail2ban like everyone else.

Comment: @MichaelHampton didn't knew it exists, so made my own script for that, it blocks whole AS by the fireawll for certain services lol. But the solution with timeout looks better for me. No sense to bruteforce passwords if each failed attempt takes 20 seconds or more. At the other hand, it won't affect "legal" users at all. I suppose this solution is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and this link really helped me out:
https://lists.exim.org/lurker/message/20120201.122116.eec741e8.en.html

Here's how it's done:

```
acl_smtp_auth = acl_check_auth
acl_smtp_quit = acl_check_quit
acl_smtp_notquit = acl_check_notquit
acl_smtp_mail = acl_check_mail
acl_smtp_connect = acl_check_connect

begin acl

acl_check_auth:
  drop  message = authentication is allowed only once per message in order \
                  to slow down bruteforce cracking
        set acl_m_auth = ${eval10:0$acl_m_auth+1}
        condition = ${if >{$acl_m_auth}{2}}
        delay = 22s

  drop  message = blacklisted for bruteforce cracking attempt
        set acl_c_authnomail = ${eval10:0$acl_c_authnomail+1}
        condition = ${if >{$acl_c_authnomail}{4}}
        continue = ${run{SHELL -c "echo $sender_host_address \
           >>$spool_directory/blocked_IPs; \
           \N{\N echo Subject: $sender_host_address blocked; echo; echo \
           for bruteforce auth cracking attempt.; \
           \N}\N | EXIMBINARY WARNTO"}}

  accept

acl_check_quit:
  warn  condition = ${if def:authentication_failed}
        condition = $authentication_failed
        logwrite = :reject: quit after authentication failed: \
                            ${sg{$sender_rcvhost}{\N[\n\t]+\N}{\040}}
        ratelimit = 7 / 5m / strict / per_conn
        continue = ${run{SHELL -c "echo $sender_host_address \
           >>$spool_directory/blocked_IPs; \
           \N{\N echo Subject: $sender_host_address blocked; echo; echo \
           for bruteforce auth cracking attempt.; \
           \N}\N | EXIMBINARY WARNTO"}}

acl_check_notquit:
  warn  condition = ${if def:authentication_failed}
        condition = $authentication_failed
        logwrite = :reject: $smtp_notquit_reason after authentication failed: \
                            ${sg{$sender_rcvhost}{\N[\n\t]+\N}{\040}}
        condition = ${if eq{$smtp_notquit_reason}{connection-lost}}
        ratelimit = 7 / 5m / strict / per_conn
        continue = ${run{SHELL -c "echo $sender_host_address \
           >>$spool_directory/blocked_IPs; \
           \N{\N echo Subject: $sender_host_address blocked; echo; echo \
           for bruteforce auth cracking attempt.; \
           \N}\N | EXIMBINARY WARNTO"}}

acl_check_mail:
  accept set acl_c_authnomail = 0

acl_check_connect:
  drop  message = $sender_host_address locally blacklisted for a bruteforce \
                  auth (login+password) cracking attempt
        condition = ${if exists{$spool_directory/blocked_IPs}}
        condition = ${lookup{$sender_host_address}lsearch\
                    {$spool_directory/blocked_IPs}{1}{0}}

  accept
```

Comment: Wow! have no words to express my gratitude! Thank you!

Comment: What is in the link? Remember that not everyone can view external links, and eventually the link may break. All the necessary details should be in your answer.

Comment: Good point. Could you copy/paste it here please?

Comment: https://lists.exim.org/lurker/message/20120201.122116.eec741e8.en.html